# How do you get the squared amplitude for the decay of the Higg's boson to W+ W- bosons from the matrix element?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, higgs, electroweak

I have the matrix element from the Feynman rules, but can't work out how to get to the squared amplitude summed over final spin states. Online sources seem to use some identities but never specify which they have used. I think it is something to do with the polarisation states of the W bosons and the fact the W bosons are on-shell as the Higg's boson was very heavy.

Comment: So the standard $\sum \varepsilon^\mu \varepsilon^{*\nu} = g^{\mu\nu}$ is not enough?

Comment: @ConnorBehan I believe that only works for massless bosons, not bosons with mass such as W/Z bosons. This is because that identity should have an additional term composed of momenta.